# Program crahes on malloc function - syntax correct, dont know why

Tags: c, memory-management, crash, malloc

The program crashes on the first malloc of command. I have no idea why. All the values being passed in are correct, and as far as I can tell there is no issue with the syntax of the statement. Oddly, when I put in debug print statements, the program sometimes gets to the first strcpy before crashing. I honestly have no idea what is going wrong.

```
void email(char *name, char *email, char *message, char *header)
{
   FILE* script = fopen("email.ps1", "w");

   char staticArgs[] = "$EmailFrom = \"msomeemail@outlook.com\"\n$SMTPServer = \"smtp-mail.outlook.com\"\n$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, 587)\n$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true\n$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(\"someemail@outlook.com\", \"apasswrd\")\n$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)";
   char emailTo[] = "$EmailTo = ";
   char subject[] = "$Subject = ";
   char body[] = "$Body = ";
   
   char *command = (char *)malloc( (strlen(emailTo) + strlen(email) + 2) );

   strcpy(command, emailTo);
   strcat(command, email);
   strcat(command, "\n");
   fputs(command, script);
   printf("command: %s\n", command);
   memset(command, '0', strlen(command));

   command = (char *)realloc(command, (strlen(subject) + strlen(header) + 2) * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(command, subject);
   strcat(command, header);
   strcat(command, "\n");
   command[strlen(command)] = '\0';
   fputs(command, script);
   printf("command: %s\n", command);
   memset(command, '0', strlen(command));

   command = (char *)realloc(command, (strlen(body) + strlen(message) + 2) * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(command, body);
   strcat(command, message);
   strcat(command, "\n");
   command[strlen(command)] = '\0';
   fputs(command, script);
   printf("command: %s\n", command);

   fputs(staticArgs, script);

   fclose(script);

   system("powershell -command \"& .\\email.ps1\"");
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the program crashes at the first malloc? That seems unlikely. Also `email` is not defined in the shown code, please provide a [mre].

Comment: If there is any error displayed please include it in the question

Comment: I found the definition of `email`, though it was well hidden. Please focus on the other parts of my first comment.

Comment: Using the same identifier ("email") for different things, though legal, is unwise.

Comment: What do you intend this to do? `command[strlen(command)] = '\0';` If it lacks a terminator, then using strlen to calculate the position for the missing terminator won't work.

Comment: Use a debugger. Step, step, step, crash,....oh that's it.

Comment: I would add a check to make sure that your fopen call didn't return NULL.